# how to understand onOptionItemSeleted()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am fairly new to android.Recently I have been following this tutorial about making a navigation drawer for my app. Most of it seem pretty straightforward(http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android). However,I am confused about what role onOptionItemSelected plays in the activity.

`if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {return true;}`

if I remove the code above , the navigation drawer won't show when I click the toggle icon, and I am curious what is happening behind the scene when I include it and click on the drawer toggle icon.

Also what is the difference between returning false and true...I tried it out but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onOptionsItemSelected()` is a method found to return menu item to perform action on it, if somehow its triggered. 
check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) for more info.

> now why the drewer is not opening when you remove this method?

because it does open it.

> how!

as i mentioned earlier this method returned a menu item that you have selected in this case the drawer icon which is located on the action bar.

> what is the difference between returning false and true?

here it does perform the action regardless the returned data, it actually doesn't use the returned value so that won't effect the action that have been taken.
hope this will help.

Comment: "This method passes the MenuItem selected"....where does that MenuItem get passed to?

Comment: we overide it from Activity class, check out the documentation.

Comment: ahh i see. btw..is there a way to look at the source code?

Comment: thanks for the help I understand what is going on now lol after reading some source code

Comment: np, glad i could help